# 2D move transform with pyproj

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj, 2d, move

Let's say I want to move my 2D coordinate system by A and B meters in pyproj. How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

A translation of coordinates is an affine conversion.

It can be done, with `pyproj`, through a PROJ [Affine Transformation](https://proj.org/operations/transformations/affine.html) pipeline:

```py
from pyproj import Transformer
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3,suppress=True)

# points list in [X,Y,Z]
points = [[0,0,0],
        [1,0,0],
        [0,1,0],
        [0,0,1],
        [-1,0,0],
        [0,-1,0],]

# transpose the points to get coordinates lists
coords = np.array(points).T 

# parameters for the affine conversion
a = 10.123
b = 20.456

# declare the pipeline string
pipeline_str = (
    "+proj=pipeline "
    "+step +proj=affine +xoff={} +yoff={}".format(a,b)
)

# Transformer instance
transf = Transformer.from_pipeline(pipeline_str)

# transform the coordinates
new_coords = transf.transform(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2])

# transpose the transformed coordinates to get points list
new_points = np.array(new_coords).T
print(new_points)
```

Retruns:

```py
[[10.123 20.456  0.   ]
 [11.123 20.456  0.   ]
 [10.123 21.456  0.   ]
 [10.123 20.456  1.   ]
 [ 9.123 20.456  0.   ]
 [10.123 19.456  0.   ]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great!

Comment: May I ask also what would be the pyproj pipeline to perform scaling of x and y by different scalars?  I am also looking for a rotation transform - that one would be great to have too:)   Background for my question: I have 2 points within one CRS (lets say XY1 system) and I have the coordinates of these points in XY2 CRS. XY1 transformed into XY2 as the result of movement, scaling and rotation. Looks like pyproj is a very strong tool. Can I use it to find a transformation matrix between XY1 and XY2?

Comment: I don't know if `pyproj` does the coefficients calculation. All the parameters are defined in the PROJ Affine Transformation matrix, but I think that you need to calculate them. The scale must be included in the rotation parameters.